# Git Diff defining incorrect hunk header for cpp file

Tags: c++, git, git-diff

I am using git diff to find out which methods have changed. Evidently its defining the hunk header incorrectly (as shown below) due to which I am not able to find a way to get the list of changed methods.

```
    @@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ void func2(){
     
     void func1(){
         cout<<"Function 1"<<endl;
    -    int i=1000;
    +    int i=100;
         while(i>0){
             func2();
             i--;
```

Here the change is in func1() but the hunk header is at func2(). I have tried changing some test functions, turns out it always selects the line/function above the required function as the hunk header.

I have tried creating a *.gitattributes* file in the root directory and placing `*.cpp diff=cpp` in order to enable cpp for diff, unfortunately that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is _hunk_ a word from the programming jargon? Besided, maybe showing the _relevant_ content of the file in the two commits would be useful, so we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Define "hunk" please?

Comment: A "hunk" is a section from a diff. A file could report 1 or multtiple hunks on a diff (actually, 0 hunks is a possibility.... if changing flags, for example)/

Comment: Pertaining to git diff, hunk is the section which contains the change and the beginning of the hunk is defined as the hunk header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that this diff *is* in function `func2`.

Note that the diff begins with a blank line, followed by the definition of function `func1`.  This definition is inside the diff-hunk, so the diff-hunk begins *before* the function.  Presumably, above the blank line we'll find more of the code of `func2`.  That's the context that `git diff` is telling you about: what comes *before* the diff.

One can (rather reasonably!) argue that the only change *within* the diff is within function `func2`, but then what should Git do with a diff hunk that reads, e.g.:

```
 T f1() {
+    new_call();
     return somevalue;
 }
 T f2() {
-    old_call();
     return somevalue;
 }
```

Here, the diff affects two functions, `f1` and `f2`, internally.  Git's answer to "how to label this" is to start above the entire text, and search backwards for some regular expression.  If that matches `f0`, that's the label that goes on the diff.

(Side note: the built in regexps work pretty well, but won't recognize all possible legal function definitions in all languages.  Changing the amount of context displayed should help for this particular example, though you would have to shrink it down to at most 1 line.)

Comment: You mentioned that it searches backwards for some regular expression, then why is it skipping func1 and going all the way to the way to the func above that. Also when there is no function above the current function then the ouput is blank.

Comment: Your diff hunk starts at line 22. What's at line 21, and what's at the lines before line 21? That's where Git is searching: from line 21, upwards. That's also why the header has no label when there is no earlier function.

Comment: You are correct, the line 22 is a blank line and before that is the entire func2. Thats why its going for func2. Is there any way to get func1 ie the method in which the change is present.

Comment: With Git written the way it is, you can only try reducing the number of context lines, as I said in my answer. If you want Git to behave differently, well, it *is* open source: clone it and have at the code. :-)

Comment: One last query, if its the default git behaviour then why are some threads recommending to use git diff or git log to find out the changed method when it will always point at something above the method. Btw I am marking your answer, thanks.

Comment: If you *aren't* hitting this sort of edge case, `git diff` *will* find the function (provided the regexp is sufficient). The `git log` code uses the same technique but starts closer to the correct line, so that as long as you're looking at any line within the function, with the definition at an earlier line, that works better than `git diff`, with its expandable hunk context.